# Android studio don't let me use primaryKeys for Room

Tags: kotlin, save, entity, android-room

In order to set uniqueness for the `entities` saved, I set `primaryKeys` like this:

```
@Entity(primaryKeys = ["name", "slidingDoorType"])
data class ParameterGroup(override var name: String, override var parameterIds: HashSet<Int>, var userCreated: Boolean, @PrimaryKey var slidingDoorType: String? = ""): FilterGroup, Parcelable {
    override var selected: Boolean = true
}
```

rather than using the standard `@PrimaryKey`. This however produces an error when trying to build the app:

> > Execution failed for task ':commonmodel:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> > A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
> > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

Not too familiar with room to know what I'm doing wrong. But as soon as I revert to the old way of using `@PrimaryKey` I can build and run the app...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is `@PrimaryKey var slidingDoorType: String? = ""` declaration. the issue is that you can't have nullable fields as primary keys.

In order to fix this change the type to non-nullable and remove the `@PrimaryKey` because you have already included this field using the `primaryKeys` property of `@Entity`.

```
var slidingDoorType: String = ""
```

Comment: Ah, nice, it worked great, thanks!